# Memory address of a memory address in a machine? (C language)

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Today out of curiosity, i tried something very weird:

**The Code :**

```
int num = 2;
int * point = &num;

printf("%p\n" , &point);
```

**The Question :**

1) The first thing i do is i append the address of variable `num` to pointer `point` , after that i use `printf()` to print out the address stores in the pointer `point`.

2) Later , i just try to modify the code(Above Code) to see what behavior it will gives , that is by using the `printf()` to print out the address of pointer `point` instead of printing out the address stores in pointer `point` which is the address of variable `num`.

3) Still it will print me the address although the address is different to the address of the variable `num` , just wanna know does this behavior is well defined in C standard??Why does a pointer has its own address too because i thought its job is to store other variable address.

*Thanks for spending time reading this.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A pointer is just another variable, and hence also needs a place to live.

Answer (score 5):

```
|----------|                             
|   point  |                            
|          |  1000                       
|   2000   |                             
|----------|                           
      |        
      |
      |
      |
      -------------------->|----------|
                           |   num    |
                           |          |  2000
                           |    2     |     
                           |----------|
```

The pointer `point` itself is also a variable and it needs some space in the memory to reside at. As shown above it points/stores the memory location where `num` is stored (`2000`) in memory, but for `point` to exist it itself needs a separate memory location (`1000`).

Answer (score 1):

Everything in your computer is ones and zeroes. Just as an int variable is just ones and zeroes at a specific memory location, a pointer is also just that. The difference is how your program decides to threat the contents of that memory cell. If you declare a pointer, it will use the memory cell to store the address of some data, yet the memory cell where that is stored must also have an address, like everything else.

This isn't so much about the C language, but rather about how a computer works.